# passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`but this dictionary requires'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, runtime-error

i'm tryng to show a list of my customers in my view i got this error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PDF.View_model.Customers]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`

in fill my list in the model layer and pass it throw pdf.view_model.View_model which is

```
   public IEnumerable<Customers> GetAllCustomers(int? _id)
    {
        Ref_customers = new List<Customers>();
        CList = new List<Models.EF_Model.Customer>();
        foreach (var item in CList)
        {
            Ref_customers.Add(new Customers() { id = item.Id, FName = item.FName, LName = item.LName, Paid = item.Paid });
        }
        return Ref_customers;
```

and in my model

```
 ` public  List<EF_Model.Customer> GetAllCustmers(int? _id)
        {
            using (var Context = new EF_Model.CoolerEntities())
            {
                return (_id.HasValue ? Context.Customers.Where(p => p.Id == _id).ToList() : Context.Customers.ToList());
            }
        }`
```

and finally in my Controller

`

```
      public ActionResult Index(int? id)
        {
            Ref_ViewModel = new View_model.View_Model();
            return View(Ref_ViewModel.GetAllCustomers(id));
        }
`
```

and in my view i posted a small amount of it,it show a list of customers in the end by a foreach statement

```
    `
@model IEnumerable<PDF.View_model.Customers>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Paid)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Password)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Paid)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Password)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

model.customer is simply a DTO of my table i also have one in my view_model.Customer

how can i convert list to IEnumerable ?i know a list is IEnumrable just don't know what to do

i'm confused

Comment: The last part of the error message is missing - _...of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<WHAT>_

Comment: @StephenMuecke  IEnumerable 1[PDF.Models.EF_Model.Customer]'.

Comment: You have 2 Customer classes, PDF.View_model.Customers and PDF.Models.EF_Model.Customer?

Comment: Stack over flow wont let me post more than 150 characters sorry for that

Comment: @sachin yes one made by .Net and the other one by my self (so i can insert DataAnnotation)

Comment: They are different types. Change the view to match the model your passing - `@model IEnumerable<PDF.View_model.Customers>`

Comment: In your View, you are using EF_Model.Customer, but you seem to be passing the other type from Controller.

Comment: @StephenMuecke what you said works but it won't show any data

Comment: Are you passing ant data? And you have not shown your view and how you displaying the data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list indeed is `IEnumerable<PDF.View_model.Customers>`, but what you need is `IEnumerable<PDF.Models.EF_Model.Customer>`.

It's not the `List` that's not matching, it's its generic parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be having 2 Customer classes. You are passing one type from the controller and using the other one as `Model` in your View.

Either you need to update your View to use the other Type `PDF.View_model.Customers`, or make the controller pass `ViewModel` of Type `PDF.Models.EF_Model.Customer`